# Jquery .position() not working

Tags: jquery

This is my javascript method

```
function showToolTip(message, controlId) {
            var webControl = controlId;
            var position = webControl.position();
            $("#ShowInfo").show();
            $("#ShowInfo").html(message);
            $("#ShowInfo").css({ top: position.top, left: position.left });
        }
```

And this is my asp.net textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoadCode" runat="server"onMouseOver="showToolTip('This indicates the load code',this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

But this gives me an error that object not supported.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a jQuery object as you're passing `this`, which is the native DOM node.

You have to wrap it first to make it work with jQuery methods

```
function showToolTip(message, controlId) {
        var webControl = $(controlId); // wrapped
        var position = webControl.position();
        $("#ShowInfo").show();
        $("#ShowInfo").html(message);
        $("#ShowInfo").css({ top: position.top, left: position.left });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem possibly I can see is that attributes are not separated by space

`runat="server"onMouseOver="showToolTip('This indicates the load code',this)"`

It should be like this

`runat="server" onMouseOver="showToolTip('This indicates the load code',this)"`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the reason , that just because  you have named the `this` object in your function as `controlID` , it does not actually become an id. It still is the `this object`. So you need to extract this object and work with that .

So, here goes :

**JS :**

```
function showToolTip(message, controlObject) {

    var webControl = $(controlObject);
    var position = webControl.position();
console.log("position::"+position.top)
    $("#ShowInfo").show();
    $("#ShowInfo").html(message);
    $("#ShowInfo").css({ top: position.top, left: position.left });
}
```

**Working Fiddle  :** http://jsfiddle.net/Tf9gm/